# Crispy forms .wrap or .update_attributes buggy after previous creation of layout object

Tags: permissions, django-crispy-forms

I have the situation that I want to layout a specific User form for the UpdateView and after that want to check if the fields need to be readonly, depending on a provided parameter. But I get a "KeyError" exception with exeption value "u'wrapper_class'".

**My example in my users.views.py**

```
form_helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
            _('Personal information'),
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            Field('password', type='hidden')
        ),
        HTML('<br/>'),
        Fieldset(
            _('Permissions'),
            'groups',
            Field('user_permissions', size=20)
        ),
        Field('date_joined', type='hidden'),
        'is_active'
    )

form_helper[:].wrap(Field, readonly=has_no_change_permission)
```

where has_no_change_permission evaluates to True or False.
This last line does not work, I get the above mentioned error.

Why? This error does not tell me much. The execption location is:
[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py in **delitem**, line 75

And by the way:

```
form.helper[:].update_attributes(readonly=True)
```

does not seem to work at all, I has no effect (no error message either). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Crispy Forms. It's fixed in v1.5.2